# How do you re-introduce code into Git?

Tags: git

I added some code to our Git repository.  However, the other team deleted my new files and changes and committed a version with my code gone.  I've tried to go back to my old commit and re-merge my changes to bring them back, but that doesn't work.  I suppose the fact that there is a newer version with the code deleted means the repo doesn't want to accept that code anymore.

How do I bring back my old code and then re-introduce it into the repo?

Comment: what's the error? it's best to talk to the other team about the reasons.  you might need to checkout your old commit again and resolve merge conflicts manually

Comment: They just deleted files.  They are pretty new to commit just like me.  I'm 99% sure it was error on their part because they definitely didn't need to delete every file I introduced.

Answer (score 3):

Git is not preventing your files from being re-added.  Rather, it sounds like you are trying to merge a commit that is an ancestor of the current branch tip.  This is a no-op in Git, as that commit is already merged.

It sounds like you want to do a partial revert of the change that removed your code instead.

Assuming that you know the commit identifier that removed your changes:

```
git revert --no-commit $COMMIT
```

This will apply that particular commit in reverse and stage the changes.  Don't commit yet, as that would undo all of the changes.  First, you have to un-stage the legitimate changes introduced in that commit.

Check `git status` and then reset each file that you do *not* want to revert using `git reset $FILE`.  This will unstage any changes made in that file.  (It will *not* restore the file in the working directory.)

If you need to partially revert a file (remove some changes in that file but not others) then use `git reset --patch $FILE`, which will prompt you for each change made in that file.  Discard each change that you *do* want to keep as-is from the commit.

At any point you can see what the current commit will change using `git diff --cached`.  Commit the result when the diff reflects the restoration of the removed files as well as whatever other changes were incorrectly made in the erroneous commit.

Answer (score 2):

There is nothing in Git that will prevent code from being re-added just because it was added and removed before.  You just need to make the changes, `git add` them, and `git commit` them.

Answer (score 0):

you could simply `cherry-pick` the commits that introduced your code:

```
mkdir test
cd test
git init
echo "foo" > foo.txt
echo "bar" > bar.txt
git add foo.txt; git commit foo.txt -m "added FOO"
git add bar.txt; git commit bar.txt -m "added BAR"
git rm  foo.txt; git commit foo.txt -m "removed FOO"
# the next line will recreate the deleted 'foo.txt' 
#      by cherry-picking the commit that created it
git cherry-pick HEAD~2
```